# Google maps android v2 crashes

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app i use google sample in my eclipse and use code basic map.java but when i run my app crash and down!
When I use step by step with google show map tutorial this link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=pt-ZA

No problem.
My min Sdk:10 And target Sdk 19 and compile:19

---

my LogCat:
06-07 01:23:11.180: W         /GooglePlayServicesUtil(1813):         Google Play services is missing.
But I installed Google play services!

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: Okay my friend please wait

Comment: where u run ur app in `emulator` or `real device`

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: have you added googleplayservices library project?

Comment: Yes I added google playservice.

Comment: right click on your project -> properties -> Android... I guess within the library you will see the Google play service is with red cross right?

Comment: R u running it in real device or emulator?

Comment: yes I run my tablet and smart phone or emulator,but al crashes!

Comment: I right click on android project and properties I see my google play service and select

Comment: have u copied `google play service lib` while importing into **same workspace** of ur project located

Comment: how can I copu google play service?

Comment: just right click on googleservices lib project and copy it and paste at workspace of your project.

Comment: Yes I copy paste but soo crash!

Comment: @user3703052 : just don't copy paste it manually while u import `google play service lib` there was an option in `Eclipse` `copy project into workspace` check that check box

Answer (score 0):

There can be two scenarios

1. Project must be imported google play services.
2. In the AndroidManifest must have
   `<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in the child of `<application>` tag.

Edited :

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application   <!-- Application Tag -->
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data    <!--child of application tag -->
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAvGvbXJD4N5PC_YT2EvdcPgP9mx9YCMs4" />
    <!-- activity declarations -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.sample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: I added this tag but what is child  of <application>?

Comment: post your code and logcat. Then only can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an actual device then you also need to have the Google Play Services app installed on the device.  You can download it from Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms